# GNOME desktop icon creation

Tags: user-interface, icons, desktop, gnome

I have extensive experience administrating Linux (various distros) command-line.

Recently, I've been tasked to be the administrator for some end-users that use GNOME.  Being an old CDE administrator (showing my age), I see opportunities to create desktop icons and/or menu entries to automate various activities or start applications.

Is there a good primer on that process?  Is there a way to create a toolbar similar to the one on CDE?

Answer (score 0):

To enable desktop icons you will need the [Desktop Icons NG (DING)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) extension . To create an application launch menu, you can use the [ArcMenu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3628/arcmenu/) extension. If you want to modify the icons in the application grid you can use the **MenuLibre** program. I don't know which linux distribution you are using, but I imagine that MenuLibre will be available through the distribution's official repository. I apologize if I didn't properly understand your question.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 7.

Wow!  I'm surprised it doesn't come with all the tools one needs to customize and modify.  Does it still use a similar hierarchy of customization as CDE:  System default, Admin default, user default (/usr/dt, /etc/dt, ~/.dt)?

I've located a System Admin guide.  I'll take a look at it next week:  https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/.

Comment: The more I admin Linux, the less I like it.  Options are great (e.g., OSS extensions and utilities).  Too many options are overwhelming.  I was looking at a Gnome extension libary earlier today and was blown away and the choices for something as simple as a Dock extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/).  I don't have time to exhaustively evaluate each and every one when trying to architect/configure systems for my organization.